# Azure mobile services javascript Update from the insert function

Tags: javascript, mobile, azure

I am creating a mobile application for windows phone 8, iOs android. I'm using windows azure for holding some profile application and some device information. I have very little experience with JavaScript although after banging my head against a brick wall all day its starting to click i think. This being said you'll probably laugh at my code below.

This (below) is the insert statement for a table called Devices.

im trying to do a normal insert if there isn't currently any record for the userId.

If there is already a record then update that record instead.

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
  item.userId = user.userId;

  var deviceTable = tables.getTable('Devices');

  deviceTable
    .where({
      userId: user.userId
    }).read({
    success: function(results) {
      if (results.length > 0) {
        // Device record was found. Continue normal execution.
        deviceTable.where({
        userID : user.userId}).update({
           //i put this here just because i thought there had to be a response
           success: request.respond(statusCodes.OK, 'Text length must be under 10')
        }) ;
        console.log('updated position ok');

      } else {
        request.execute();
        console.log('Added New Entry',user.userId);
        //request.respond(statusCodes.FORBIDDEN, 'You do not have permission to submit orders.');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want something like this:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
  item.userId = user.userId;
  var deviceTable = tables.getTable('Devices');
  deviceTable
    .where({
      userId: user.userId
    }).read({
    success: function(results) {
      if (results.length > 0) {
        //We found a record, update some values in it
        results[0].fieldName = X;
        //Update it in the DB
        deviceTable.update(results[0]);
        //Respond to the client
        request.respond(200, results[0]);
        console.log('updated position ok');

      } else {
        //Perform the insert in the DB
        request.execute();
        console.log('Added New Entry',user.userId);
        //Reply with 201 (created) and the updated item
        request.respond(201, item);
      }
    }
  });
}
```